# Search result Count from Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is the Count of Search results from Elastic Search accurate? Or is this approximate? If accurate, will it always be accurate based on what is indexed? Assuming that all documents are indexed along with all the text in them and no documents are being ingested, what is the behavior of Count of Search results? Does it change base on the volume of the index and volume of the search results. Thanks for your help!!